# Shopware Product Export Feed for Doofinder plugin

Tags: shopware

I have catalog setup under Shopware, and I have installed doofinder plugin for the search purpose. So, now I need to provide the feed urls in my doofinder and the feeds are setup as well. But, one of the feed does not generate the xml correctly. It is trying to export around 18k records. While, there is one another feed that exports around 74k records.

Can someone please throw me pointers, what can be the probable cause and solution? I am newbie to shopware, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of, which version of Shopware are you using? (5.6.7 or 6.2.2?)
For now I assume you are using 5.6.7 (or anything along the 5.6 line).

How do you generate the feeds?
Have you checked the logs in `var/log/`? Maybe there is an kinda obvious error.